# Double click to edit and add new value to li

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#li', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    input = $("<input type='text'>");
    input.appendTo('#li').focus();

});

$(document).on('focusout', 'input', function () {
    if (input.val() != "") {
        newInput = input.val();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#li').text(newInput);
    } else {
        $('#li').text(oriVal);
    }

});
```

So far, I still can't do OOP in jQuery.  Can you improve the above code?

Comment: Do not listen to such a ridiculous statement and instead have a look at these articles, they should greatly help you. http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Does this code work? You don't explain what you're trying to do, and the code and question title don't seem to match.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure how to answer this, so I went with what your code does...

1. Scope your variables.
2. Change your code to target all `li` instead of one element with the id `li`.
3. Use `this` when events are triggered to make sure you have the correct element.
4. Remove the added elements instead of hiding them.
5. Remember to call `on` using the smallest possible parent container. Possibly a `<ul>` or `<ol>`?
6. Use short circuiting where appropriate.
7. Use `jQuery.parent()` to get the appended elements parent.

Putting all those change together:

```
var oriVal;
$("#parentUL").on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
});
$("#parentUL").on('focusout', 'li > input', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().text($this.val() || oriVal); // Use current or original val.
    $this.remove();                      // Don't just hide, remove the element.
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wabLp/1/).